# Падает бот ВКонтакте на хостинге vk-api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, pythonanywhere

Сделал небольшого бота для ВКонтакте. Запускал на компьютере - хорошо, на хостинге до недавнего времени тоже все было хорошо, но с недавних пор он начал падать и насколько я понимаю - проблема не в моем коде.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1322, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 310, in recv_into
    raise timeout('The read operation timed out')
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 637, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(conn, method, url,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 306, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='im.vk.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=35)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ArsenAganesov/Gordon_Bot/vk_bot.py", line 139, in <module>
    for event in longpoll.listen():
  File "/home/ArsenAganesov/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vk_api/longpoll.py", line 621, in listen
    for event in self.check():
  File "/home/ArsenAganesov/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vk_api/longpoll.py", line 557, in check
    response = self.session.get(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='im.vk.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=35)
```

Comment: Обращайтесь в техподдержку хостинга, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal у нет как таковой поддержки

Answer (score 0):

Разработчики VK API в документации (https://vk.com/dev.php?method=using_longpoll), при подключении к серверу long poll рекомендуют устанавливать время ожидания ответа в 25 секунд, "так как некоторые прокси-серверы обрывают соединение после 30 секунд". У вас установлено 35. Меняйте на рекомендованные, количество падений сократится кратно. Но даже в этом случае, случайные вылеты возможны. Спустя несколько недель изучения VK API, так и не смог выявить природы некоторых падений приложения на удаленном сервере, поэтому решил, что для обеспечения стабильной работы бэкэнда ботов, не лишним будет воспользоваться некоторыми функциями средств развертывания, таких как restart в docker. Бот все еще будет иногда падать, но поднимать его в ручную больше не придется, за вас это сделает docker, помимо этого, можно будет собрать логи на временном отрезке, и отследить причину падений.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    try:
        your code...
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Команда pass позволяет пропустить ошибки и продолжить использование кода. Сам использую на pythonanywhere, но код все равно будет вырубаться, но намного реже. Возможно поможет.